# how to change all package name in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to change my package name in eclipse, i have tried everything, my last try was to change it from android tools-> rename application package but that didn't seem to change the package in the code files itself, i have more than one package in my app, so i selected the first one and pressed F2 then i typed in the same package name and it changed in the files, but when i selected the second package and pressed F2 i didn't want to change, it says package already exists ! i'm just wondering how the app name and package is read on Google play, is it from manifest file only ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to `right click on the package > Refacor > Rename`

[image]

Comment: Yes i do this, and because i have more than 1 package in my project the first one is changed but the second one says package already exists !

Comment: You are viewing the package view with flat presentation. Solution: click the down arrow at the right of package explorer, and select package presentation -> hierarchical