# change application's package name in manifest

Tags: android, publishing

I know this question has been asked many times, but I didn't find exact solutions which I would understand.

I have made a little game with android studio and I  would like to publish it. But then I find out that I can't use package name "com.example". How do I change this to "com.MYNAME"?

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.MYNAME.APPNAME" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/achievements"
            android:name=".Achievements"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.MYNAME.APPNAME.MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

If I change `package="com.example.MYNAME.APPNAME"`to`package="com.MYNAME.APPNAME"`, there will be errors in `android:name=".MainActivity"`, `android:name=".Achievements"`, `android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"` and `android:value="com.MYNAME.APPNAME.MainActivity"`.

Thank you for help!

Comment: This answer will help you, please have a look:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/1384010 , if you are using eclipse the please refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16630130/1384010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change .java file package name also.
Then clean the project and build again.
Because .MainActivity is still in package name "com.example.MYNAME.APPNAME"

Answer (score 1):

please do the following to change your package name to the new one

1. Right click on your project
2. Choose Android Tools
3. Choose Rename Application Package
4. Enter your new package name then click ok

Answer (score 1):

Please check this out and change com to org and then you can publish your app

https://youtu.be/A-rITYZQj0A

Comment: you also need to change the 'applicationId' field in build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything manually, Just right click on the package name > refactor > rename. Everywhere in your project the project name will be changed :)